# Items and specialized items: Multiple tables with duplicate columns, main table and detail table, or ...?

Tags: sql, t-sql, database-design

I need to store data related to "items" where there will be various different item types, all with common attributes, and then each type with its own additional attributes. I expect this is a common requirement; what's the best-practices solution? We're using SQL Server.

Let's use a made-up example:

**Vehicle** has

- Price
- Make
- Model
- Owner

(In our real data, there will be 10-15 common columns.)

**Car** is a Vehicle plus:

- Style (sedan, sports, etc.)
- Color
- EngineSize

**Boat** is a Vehicle plus:

- Displacement
- PortOfOrigin

...etc. for several types of things. In our real data, each specialized type will typically add 2-5 columns; there will be 5 types to start with. We'll be adding types over time, but probably only 3 or 4 more in total (if that). Adding types requires development, so it's not like "tags" which can be added willy-nilly by end users. We assume adding a type will require changes to the DB and client tiers, and probably the mid-tier as well. That's totally fine.

We will do lots of queries across all of the items (vehicles, in the example above); we only worry about the details of a specific item type (Car, Boat) rarely.

I see four ways to store this data:

1. Separate tables for Cars, Boats, etc., with duplicated columns.
2. One table with the `Vehicle` data, a table for the additional `Car` data, and a table for the additional `Boat` data.
3. One table of items, a separate table of item attributes with a row per additional attribute. E.g., a soft schema for the details.
4. One table with generic columns given meaning only by non-DB code.

Looking at each:

1. Separate tables for Cars, Boats, etc., with duplicated columns. E.g., roughly:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE [Cars] (
       [Id] IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
       [Price] DECIMAL (19, 4),
       [Make] NVARCHAR(200),
       [Model] NVARCHAR(200),
       [Owner] INT,
       [Id] INT PRIMARY KEY,
       [Style] NVARCHAR(200),
       [Color] NVARCHAR(200),
       [EngineSize] DECIMAL(19, 2)
   )
   CREATE TABLE [Boats] (
       [Id] IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
       [Price] DECIMAL (19, 4),
       [Make] NVARCHAR(200),
       [Model] NVARCHAR(200),
       [Owner] INT,
       [Id] INT PRIMARY KEY,
       [Displacement] DECIMAL(19, 4),
       [PortOfOrigin] NVARCHAR(200)
   )
   ```

   Simple enough, Cars go in `Cars` and Boats go in `Boats`. If we add more vehicle types, we add a table. If we add another common column, we have to go back and add it to all the vehicle tables. Reporting against vehicles in general can be done against a union view of all of the tables (being careful about the `Id` column).
2. One table with the `Vehicle` data, a table for the additional `Car` data, and a table for the additional `Boat` data. E.g., roughly:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE [Vehicles] (
       [Id] IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
       [Price] DECIMAL (19, 4),
       [Make] NVARCHAR(200),
       [Model] NVARCHAR(200),
       [Owner] INT,
       [Type] INT        -- A type ID, e.g. "Car" vs. "Boat"
   )
   CREATE TABLE [Cars] (
       [Id] INT PRIMARY KEY,
       [Style] NVARCHAR(200),
       [Color] NVARCHAR(200),
       [EngineSize] DECIMAL(19, 2)
   )
   CREATE TABLE [Boats] (
       [Id] INT PRIMARY KEY,
       [Displacement] DECIMAL(19, 4),
       [PortOfOrigin] NVARCHAR(200)
   )
   ```

   So every Car would have one row in `Vehicles` and one linked row in `Cars`. Every Boat would have one row in `Vehicles` and one linked row in `Boats`. If we add more vehicle types, we add a table. Reporting against vehicles in general can be done against just the `Vehicle` table. When retrieve details of a specific `Car` or `Boat`, we use a join.
3. One table of items, a separate table of item attributes with a row per additional attribute. E.g., a soft schema for the details. E.g., roughly:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE [Vehicles] (
       [Id] IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
       [Price] DECIMAL (19, 4),
       [Make] NVARCHAR(200),
       [Model] NVARCHAR(200),
       [Owner] INT,
       [Type] INT
   )
   CREATE TABLE [VehicleDetails] (
       [VehicleId] INT,
       [Name] NVARCHAR(200),
       [Value] NVARCHAR(MAX)
   )
   ```

   So every Car gets one row in `Vehicles` and three rows in `VehicleDetails` (one each for "Style", "Color", and "EngineSize"). Reporting is largely done against the `Vehicle` table. Reporting on details starts getting messy fast. Soft schemas have their place, mostly around user-defined data, but I'm assuming this wouldn't be a good choice here.
4. One table with generic columns given meaning only by non-DB code:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE [Vehicles] (
       [Id] IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
       [Price] DECIMAL (19, 4),
       [Make] NVARCHAR(200),
       [Model] NVARCHAR(200),
       [Owner] INT,
       [Type] INT,
       [Detail01] NVARCHAR(MAX),
       [Detail02] NVARCHAR(MAX),
       [Detail03] NVARCHAR(MAX),
       [Detail04] NVARCHAR(MAX),
       [Detail05] NVARCHAR(MAX),
       [Detail06] NVARCHAR(MAX),
       [Detail07] NVARCHAR(MAX),
       [Detail08] NVARCHAR(MAX),
       [Detail09] NVARCHAR(MAX),
       [Detail10] NVARCHAR(MAX)
   )
   ```

   So Car data would assign Style to `Detail01`, Color to `Detail02`, and EngineSize to `Detail03`; for Boats, we'd put Displacement in `Detail01` and PortOfOrigin in `Detail02`. Similarly, there may be a place for this with end-user defined schemas, but I'm guessing this wouldn't be a good answer when you can control the DB structure.

Comment: Is a relational database strictly required? Looks like using a document database for this model would be a better fit.

Comment: @Oded: Good question. In this case, yes, it has to be stored in the RDBMS, at least for now. If we get enough of these sorts of requirements, maybe we'll augment the RDBMS with a document database.

Comment: "we'll be adding more types over time" - indicates option 2 to me. A soft schema (EAV model) is a non starter as is the generic columns one.

Comment: @Oded: Yeah, I went down the soft-schema road and then said "That's not going to be good." :-) Mostly included 3 and 4 for completeness.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends.

Approach 1 is best for situations where most attributes will be common to most types.

Approach 2 is best for situations where few attributes will be common to most types.

Approach 3 is essentially approach 1, with an Entity-Attribute-Value approach to handling type-specific attributes. This approach is best for situations where most attributes will be common to most types, and it is difficult to anticipate what additional attributes will be required - it is quite common in situations that require user-created fields.

Approach 4 is not a good idea in any situation - it removes semantic content from the metadata layer into the code layer, while retaining the inflexibility of Approach 1.

There is also another possible approach - a pure [Entity-Attribute-Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) approach (essentially a blend of approaches 3 and 4). This is generally regarded as an anti-pattern, due to the complexity and poor performance produced when implemented on a RDBMS. However, there are some situations where it is the only approach possible - primarily, where the entity relationships are not known in advance.

Comment: Thanks, very reasonable. I've just added this info to the question: *"To give you an idea, we figure there will be on the order of 10-15 common attributes (e.g., Vehicle data), and any given specialized type (Car, Boat) will add 2-4."* So that would suggest you'd lean toward option 1...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I would say you need to consider how many additional types you expect. If it is a small amount, lean to 1, if a large amount, lean to 2.

Comment: @Oded: Thanks, you've highlighted something else I left out of the question. :-) I've added it. (Five types to start with, probably no more than another three or four over time.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I personally would lean towards approach 1, based on the relatively small number of additional attributes each type is likely to have. However, I think you are better placed to make this call than I am.

Comment: @MarkBannister: Thanks. Yes, at the end of the day we have to decide at this end with our real schema, but good to know what others think.